# Not able to show the title in PHP inside loop

Tags: php

I am not able to find the error why my title is not displaying. This is my code:

```
echo '<br /><b style="display:block";>'.$name .'</b>';
echo '<i style="color:red";>'.$class.'';
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: what does show up? does your computer explode when you run this?. More details please. I already see syntax errors with your "style"

Comment: why did you delete your code??

Comment: This question is starting to look very unclear; given the edit in the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20491779 - what does this have to do with `<?php echo $name;?>

      <?php echo $name2;?>` ? I don't see any of those variables in the original post.

Comment: @RBalasubramanian I guess they did and I don't know why that was. I rolled the question back to a previous revision. Their code is showing now and hope they won't go changing it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to echo `HTML` tags inside `PHP` script. Your code should have been written as follows. I see that closing tag `</i>` is missing as well. I hope this might solve your problem.

```
    <br />
    <b style="display:block;">
      <?php echo $name;?>
    </b>
    <i style="color:red;">
      <?php echo $class;?>
    </i>
```

Comment: why is there an edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20491779 where the OP is trying to completely change the accepted answer? I for one will reject that edit.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the  unnecessary last single quotes `''`, Also put your semicolon `;` inside the double quotes `"`

```
<?php
$title = 'this is title value'; //example title
$des = 'this is description';  // example description 
echo '<br /><b style="font-size:1.5em;">'.$title.'</b>'; 
echo '<i style="font-size:18px;">'.$des;
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/1044486